# NSDocument is marked as dirty after a save due to NSUndoManager - why?

Tags: objective-c, nsdocument, nsundomanager

So I set a breakpoint on `updateChangeCount:(NSDocumentChangeType)changeType` to see when my document was being marked as dirty.

After I save the document, it is cleared properly with `NSChangeCleared`, then IMMEDIATELY after it is called with `NSChangeDone` which increments the changed count.

Here is the stack trace of that call:

```
    0   SS                                  0x000000010000764a -[SSDocument updateChangeCount:] + 42
    1   AppKit                              0x00007fff94fdcdac -[NSDocument _changeWasDone:] + 458
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9c415c9c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9c415c2f ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke + 63
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9c415ba7 _CFXRegistrationPost + 407
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9c415912 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 50
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9c3d26d2 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1922
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9c3d1925 _CFXNotificationPost + 693
    8   Foundation                          0x00007fff9b72b0fa -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
    9   Foundation                          0x00007fff9b7ba4ad -[NSUndoManager _endUndoGroupRemovingIfEmpty:] + 535
    10  Foundation                          0x00007fff9b79b06b +[NSUndoManager(NSPrivate) _endTopLevelGroupings] + 484
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff94bd7dca -[NSApplication run] + 844
```

I haven't configured NSUndoManager in any way.  Any suggestions on how I can prevent this from occurring?

It's a problem because a user can save the document, close the window, and they are then asked to save again.

Answer (score 2):

> Undo operations are typically collected in undo groups. NSUndoManager normally creates undo groups automatically during the run loop. The first time it is asked to record an undo operation in the run loop, it creates a new group. Then, at the end of the loop, it closes the group.

You can temporarily disable undo by calling `-[NSUndoManager disableUndoRegistration]` and `-[NSUndoManager enableUndoRegistration]`. You can remove all undo actions with `-[NSUndoManager removeAllActions]`.

Comment: So I actually tried to disable and re-enable during my `writeSafelyToURL` hook, but it still fires updateChangeCount with a 0, so my document is marked as dirty again.  Any other ideas? I wish I could find what is triggering the notification that eventually calls updateChangeCount.